# MySQL Functional Index on a Varchar column with multi decimal sequence

Tags: mysql, indexing, hierarchical-data, functional-index

So I have a table where we store a sequence value of what we call a "tree".  Sort of looks like this

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
2
2.1
2.2
3
3.1
3.1.1
3.1.1.1
3.1.1.2
3.1.1.3
etc
etc
etc
```

Our application searches this tree, rebuilds the tree.  Performs operations on it.  What I am asking is if it would make sense to make a functional index on this column?  If so, what would be ideal?  Each number within the sequence?  Cast it to number from the string?  Any thoughts or idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think MySQL has any functions that do things with strings like this, except `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`. I can't think of how you would create a useful index on them.

Comment: It might be better to create a hierarchical table, where `1.1` points to `1` as its parent.

Comment: What types of searches are you doing? The index design may or may not help, depending on the specific query.

Comment: *Our application searches this tree* Searching criteria pattern? *rebuilds the tree* Details needed. *Performs operations on it.* What operations?

Comment: @Barmar - Can you please elaborate further on hierarchical table?

Comment: Something like this: `id INT PK, number_seq VARCHAR(100), parent_id INT FK REFERENCES this_table (ID)`.

Comment: If you can turn those into "001", "001.001", ..., "003001001003", then they will sort correctly (assuming no number is bigger than 999).